# Moodle email not get even after a success message

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

I can't get user verification mail even after a success message. My file permission is 755. It show success message with or with out an smtp setting. I think problem arises after my server change. But php mail function is working when I tested in separate file on server.Any Idea about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please install test email moodle plugin and test email using that plugin. it will show the error if email fail.